# How to let a node insert a new line if a text is long?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bookcover, tikzpagenodes

I'm designing a cover with the following code

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadows}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [   overlay,
    remember picture,
    mynode/.style={left,fill=yellow!10,general shadow={shadow scale=1, shadow xshift=-0.8ex, shadow yshift=-0.8ex,
            opacity=1, fill=gray!50}},
    ]
    \fill[red!30!gray] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    
    \node[mynode] at ($(current page.north east)+(-2,-4)$) {\fontsize{25}{30}\selectfont \textbf{Probability, Mathematical Statistics, and Stochastic Processes}};
    
    \node[above right] at ($(current page.south west)+(3.5,5)$) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{cover_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}};
    
    \node[mynode] at ($(current page.north east)+(-0.8, -27)$) {\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont converted from \texttt{www.randomservices.org} to PDF by Lê Anh Dũng};
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Because the title is `Probability, Mathematical Statistics, Stochastic Processes`, which is long for the first node. I have a problem

[image]

Could you please help me extend the first node to the second line? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the text width inside a node by adding `text width=7cm` as an option to the node command.